# How to retrieve a variable from a list located in a dictionary, located in a list? two

Tags: python

okay so if I have the following:

```
fruits = [{
    name:apple,
    color:[red,green],
    weight:1
}, {
    name:banana,
    color:[yellow,green],
    weight:1
}, {
    name:orange,
    color:orange,
    weight:[1,2]
}]
```

So I need to write a program that will get the weight and the name by color.
Can someone show me how to do that.

```
def findCarByColor(theColor):
    z=0
    for i in carList:
        for a,b in i.iteritems():
            #print a,"a", b, "b"
            for d in b:
                #print d
                if d is theColor:

                    print carList [0][b][0]



    return z
print findCarByColor("Red")
```

Comment: SO really isn't a "write me some code" site .. but we'll be happy to help you write your own code. What have you tried? Are you stuck on anything particular? Show us some code, ask some questions, and you'll get the help you need.

Comment: Now that you've posted the function you tried, you need to tell us what you want to know. Instead of "Can someone show me how to do that?", you might consider telling us what happens when you run the above code and tell us what you expect as output.

Comment: If this is the code you're using, your keys and values aren't proper - the strings aren't defined.  You may want to look into that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the example dictionary. You can also check to see if a string exists in a list without having to manually loop through it.

```
fruits = [{
    'name':"apple",
    'color':["red","green"],
    'weight':1
}, {
    'name':"banana",
    'color':["yellow","green"],
    'weight':1
}, {
    'name':"orange",
    'color':"orange",
    'weight':[1,2]
}]

def findit(fruits,color):
    for indv in fruits:
        if color in indv['color']:
            return indv['name'], indv['weight']

print findit(fruits,"red")
```

result: `('apple', 1)`

This function will only return one instance. If you need to find every instance that green appears for example, this second function will work:

```
def findit2(fruits,color):
    return [(x['name'],x['weight']) for x in fruits if color in x['color']]

print findit2(fruits,"green")
```

The result will be: `[('apple', 1), ('banana', 1)]`

If you are confused by the notational aspect of how I did that in one line, you can either see how it is done via [pythons docs here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). If you want a more simplified version. You can modify the first method (findit) to yield:

```
def findit3(fruits,color):
    mylist = []
    for indv in fruits:
        if color in indv['color']:
            mylist.append(  (indv['name'], indv['weight'])  )
    return mylist
```

Comment: what if there is a second dictionary and another array in there?

Comment: what if there is an another dict and an array? fruits = [{
    'name':"apple",
    'color':["red","green"],
    'weight':1
}, {
    'name':"banana",
    'color':["yellow","green"],
    'weight':1
}, {
    'name':"orange",
    'color':"orange",
    'weight':[1,2]
}]

Comment: @thebiggerchadder Where is the difference in the fruits list? Your list looks pretty much the same as the one I made. Did you want to add more complexity by layering more lists and dictionaries than what was shown in the example? Could you show me what you need to parse out? You mentioned a second dictionary in "there", but could you specify "there"?